# SEGFAULT with embedded python after changing entry point

Tags: c, python-3.x

I'm trying to use python embedded in c and change the entrypoint.  The motivation for this is that I'm also [Unity](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity) to write unit tests and I need an different (ie non-main) entry point in my test runner because some of the code I'm testing resides in the same file as that main for the application.  However, attempts to initialize python (ie `Py_Initialize()`) cause a SEGFAULT.

Using the code below,

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program); /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0)
    {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}

int entrypoint(void)
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale("entrypoint", NULL);
    Py_SetProgramName(program); /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0)
    {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

everything is fine with `main`,

```
$ gcc embedded_python.c -fPIE $(python3.10-config --cflags) $(python3.10-config --ldflags --embed) -o embedded_python
$ ./embedded_python
Today is Thu Dec  7 22:01:51 2023
```

when changing the entrypoint the code segfaults,

```
$ gcc embedded_python.c -fPIE $(python3.10-config --cflags) $(python3.10-config --ldflags --embed) -o embedded_python_entry -Wl,--entry=entrypoint
$ ./embedded_python_entry 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I understand somethings don't get set when changing entrypoint, eg `argv[0]` isn't set which I hardcoded the program name, but can't figure out what else is missing.

I tried adding `Py_SetPythonHome("/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu");` before the call to `Py_Initalize()` as suggested in another thread but still no joy.

Any help would be appreciated and Thanks! in advance.

Comment: Run your code under the debugger. Add `-g` to compilation. Then, invoke with `gdb ./embedded_python_entry` and type `run`. Then, type `bt` to get a stack traceback. But, honestly, why are you using `-Wl,--entry=entrypoint` at all??? Try leaving it off. You _need_ the _standard_ entry point (and code) used by `gcc` programs (e.g. `crt0.o` et. al.) to set things up correctly so you can invoke `main` If the build you do includes this, then fine. But ... You may want to build a normal C program but link to the python _library_